# Unable to parse "2021-11-03T16:57:18.000 00:00" in Carbon

Tags: laravel, datetime, php-carbon

I need to parse date `2021-11-03T16:57:18.000 00:00` with Carbon but I could not successful

> InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 582:
>   Unexpected data found.
>   Trailing data

how I am using in code

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',$cerValidTo)
```

and if I use

`Carbon::parse($cerValidTo)`

> DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2021-11-03T16:57:18.000 00:00) at position 24 (0): Double time specification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the `00:00` part:

```
Carbon::parse('2021-11-03T16:57:18.000')
```

If you need to make it `00:00`, use the `startOfDay()` method instead:

```
Carbon::parse('2021-11-03T16:57:18.000')->startOfDay()
```

Comment: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2021-11-03T16:57:18.000 00:00) at position 24 (0): Double time specification

Comment: @BilalMaqsood you didn't remove the `00:00` as I've shown.

Comment: How can I remove that ??

Comment: @BilalMaqsood there are many ways. You can do `str_before($date, ' ')`. Or you could use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php)